# Retropie Retroarch not accepting keyboard keys for hotkeys

Tags: keyboard, retropie

used image: retropie-v3.3.1-rpi2.img
Raspberry 2

I am setting up a cabinet which works with 2 Joysticks and a Keyboard-Hack

2 Joysticks are Fully set up and working with RetroArch (mame2003-libretro)

The keyboard-Hack is wired to Pushbuttons, reacting like pressing Numbers. num2, num3, num6 and num7.

These buttons are recognized and useable when setting up with Emustation and numbers are written in shell too.

but when im in RetroArch Menu > Input > Bind Hotkeys, no keyboard entries are recognized. i navigate to (example) Pause toggle, Window opens and says Push Botton or Keyboard, Counts down to zero and doesnt change the keys,

i changed the retroarch.cfg in /all and /lr-mame2003 to the keys [pause_toggle = "num3"] without any effects...

any ideas?